# Write Files to WPD device via MTP C#/VB.net

Tags: .net, usb, wpd

I would like to write an application that will copy MP3 files to a SanDisk Sansa M240.  The SanDisk doesn't have a drive letter and uses MTP for file transfer. 
I stumbled through the sample of connecting to the device at : http://blogs.msdn.com/dimeby8/archive/2006/09/27/774259.aspx

but once connected, I can't figure out how to actually copy files / create folders on the device.

I am very surprised that there aren't any .Net wrappers for this COM library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like dimeby8 posted some code that handles data transfers.  Check other posts in his blog, especially:

[Sending MTP commands through WPD part 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dimeby8/sending-mtp-commands-through-wpd-part-1-without-a-data-phase)

[Sending MTP commands through WPD part 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dimeby8/sending-mtp-commands-through-wpd-part-2-data-to-the-device)

[Sending MTP commands through WPD part 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dimeby8/sending-mtp-commands-through-wpd-part-3-data-from-device)

Answer (score 2):

To transfer files through MTP with c#:

1. Download this NuGet package: [PortableDevices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PortableDevices/)
2. Add references to these 4 COM libraries:

   - PortableDeviceClassExtension
   - PortableDeviceConnectApi
   - PortableDeviceTypes
   - PortableDeviceApi
3. Take the dll's under `obj\Debug` and put them into `bin\Debug`:

   - Interop.PortableDeviceClassExtension.dll
   - Interop.PortableDeviceConnectApiLib.dll
   - Interop.PortableDeviceTypesLib.dll
   - Interop.PortableDeviceApiLib.dll

---

Now you can use the following function to list all devices, although `FriendlyName` does not seem to be working (it returns an empty string):

```
    private IDictionary<string, string> GetDeviceIds()
    {
        var deviceIds = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var devices = new PortableDeviceCollection();
        devices.Refresh();
        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            device.Connect();
            deviceIds.Add(device.FriendlyName, device.DeviceId);
            Console.WriteLine(@"DeviceId: {0}, FriendlyName: {1}", device.DeviceId, device.FriendlyName);
            device.Disconnect();
        }
        return deviceIds;
    }
```

The next step is getting the contents from the device, which is done like so:

```
var contents = device.GetContents();
```